# Java IMAP endless loop while writing to EML

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

We got a serious problem in our system which is processing mails from IMAP and saving it as EML. Thing is, everything works in production but not on dev machine anymore, therefore we cannot make any fixes or further development. This is kind of strange, because also this example does not work:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class ReadMail {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String host = "mail";
        String user = "xxx";
        String password = "zzz";
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        Store store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect(host, user, password);
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("a");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        Message[] message = folder.getMessages();

        for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("------------ Message " + (i + 1) + " ------------");

            System.out.println(message[i].getSentDate());
            System.out.println(message[i].getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println(message[i].getSubject());

            try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("something"+i+".eml")) { // fix the name of course
                message[i].writeTo(out);
            }



        }

        folder.close(true);
        store.close();

    }
}
```

In writeTo it makes endless loop and creates file which grows until the disk is full. This is from `com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage`

```
/**
 * Write out the bytes into the given OutputStream.
 */
public void writeTo(OutputStream os)
            throws IOException, MessagingException {
if (bodyLoaded) {
    super.writeTo(os);
    return;
}
InputStream is = getMimeStream();
try {
    // write out the bytes
    byte[] bytes = new byte[16*1024];
    int count;
    while ((count = is.read(bytes)) != -1)
    os.write(bytes, 0, count);
} finally {
    is.close();
}
}
```

It will never exit from the while clause. Should it be some error on the Postfix side? The mail is multipart MIME message and the EML created are just multiple copies of EML. Only difference between prod and dev machine is HW. JDK8 is the same. Any hints?

Java mail API used:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE SOLVED:** ESET Nod32 Antivirus software intercept the IMAP traffic in that way, that the buffer never returns -1! After disabling ESET Mail, everything works.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to see if there's anything JavaMail can do to work around this problem, or if ESET is just so broken that it's hopeless.

Comment: Thanks for interest. I already contacted ESET to investigate an issue. I will try to provide Debug output next week.